# EJB3: Right way to insert initial data when application starts like Grails Bootstrap?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1, ejb-3.2

Similar to Bootstrap.groovy in Grails, how to add some initial data when an app starts?

Since in @PostContstruct method, the EntityManager is not available in Stateless session beans (or am I doing something wrong?), so what should be the right way to insert some initial data?

E.g. I want to add one Admin account in my system when the application starts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since in @PostContstruct method, the EntityManager is not available

This is not true, `@PostConstruct` is usually the right place where to retrieve initial data for a view from the db.

When application starts you can use a Singleton EJB for startup operations, like adding an admin account, and annotate the EJB with `@Startup`:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class MySingleton implements Serializable {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // here you can perform queries or transactions
    }
}
```

Enterprise Java Beans, like Singleton, are transactional by default. With Java EE 7, CDI beans become transactional if they are annotated with [`@Transactional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html).

**Links**:

- [The Java EE 7 Tutorial by Oracle: Container-Managed Transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/transactions003.htm)
- [The Java EE 7 Tutorial by Oracle: Using the @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy Annotations with CDI Managed Bean Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/cdi-basic014.htm)

Comment: First of all, thank for your reply! I was using Stateless SessionBeans and always getting the EntityManager null in PostConstruct, any idea about that?

(updated the question)

Comment: It can be null if you instantiate the EJB yourself. Instead, you should used EJBs in other container-managed beans like CDI beans and inject it using `@EJB` annotation.

Comment: Not really. I created a basic app with one EJB module and one war module. And i exposed my SessionBeans method via ReST path annotation - just 'hello world'- which works.

Then I configured database and added an EM in my SessionBean as:

@Resource
private EntityManager entityManager;    

but actually it is always null ...

Comment: Can you try with `@PersistenceContext` instead of `@Resource`? And post the Session Bean code.

Comment: Used, but I just found there is not JDBC resource created in Glassfish and I need to configure it. Thought it would be automatically created once I configured the datasource while creating the entity using Netbeans.

I need to RTFM even more, comparing to Grails.. its a bit more :p

Thanks.